# my code runs and works on some excel workbooks but not all of them, why? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a weird problem with my code VBA.

I am using excel 2010, i wrote a code which works perfectly on multiple source except some.

my code object is to copy the same cell from the same sheet from multiple workbooks and paste it into a destination workbook as a column.

My code runs on 50 workbooks without any problem, except 2.
Notice that those 2 are the same sample as the others, but of course different values.
If I ad those 2 workbooks with the other 50, I have an error message 'Error of execution'1004' and I should then stop the process.
the yellow line stand on a the formula :
`myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
    Set y = Workbooks.Open(destFullpath)`

```
    `With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A" & i + 1)
        **.Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!L2" 'date** 
        .Value = .Value
        y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A" & i + 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"  ' <-- to specify that it is a date format

    End With`
```

Do you have an idea why can this problem occur? 
what should i do? Is there anything to change with the settings etc?

Note That I have tried to save those 2 as excel without macros, so xlsx and did not run.
I tried to unprotect the sheets: did not run
I broke the link between them and other one: this didn't help either!!!

what can it be??

Thank you!!

This is the entire code :

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolderr()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and 
perform a set task on them


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim destFullpath As String
Dim myExtension As String
DimFldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim y As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User

myPath = "Z:\VBA\para_macro\"
destFullpath = "Z:\VBA\base-macro.xlsx"
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)


'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Set y = Workbooks.Open(destFullpath)

For i = 1 To y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("M1")


'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents






    With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!L2" 'date devis
        .Value = .Value
        y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A" & i + 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"  ' <-- to specify that it is a date format

    End With


    With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("B" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!E11" 'date d'installation
        .Value = .Value


    End With

With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("c" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!H5" 'type
        .Value = .Value


    End With

    With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("D" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!H8" 'montant final
        .Value = .Value
        .NumberFormat = "0.000"

    End With

    With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("E" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!K8" 'montant tarif
        .Value = .Value
        .NumberFormat = "0.000"

    End With

     With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("F" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!K10" 'remise
        .Value = .Value
         .NumberFormat = "0.000"

    End With

    With y.Sheets("Feuil1")
        .Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=$F2/$E2"
    y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "0.00%"

    End With

    With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("H" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!D6" 'société
        .Value = .Value


    End With

    With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("I" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!F8" 'ville
        .Value = .Value


    End With


    With y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("J" & i + 1)
        .Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!G5" 'nom vendeur
        .Value = .Value


    End With


'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir()

Next
'Save and Close Workbook

  y.Close saveChanges:=True
'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Impossible to accurately diagnose problem without seeing the patient. Paste the code.

Comment: Are these two workbooks opening in `Protected View` or `Read-Only` ?

Comment: Neither is "Code does not work" a valid/good error description (So please [edit] your question and add the error message) nor can anyone say whats wrong with your code if you don't show it (So please [edit] your question and add your macro code).

Comment: I have added the code! thank you!

Comment: Did you that those two workbooks have a worksheet name "Feuil1"? and, what is the value of `i` when it breaks? Besides, why do you keep opening then closing the workbook `destFullpath`? This is not good practice. Open it once then close it when finished with it.

Comment: @KoderM16 I have posted the code! but the problem is not with my code, as it works for 50 at once! the problem is with the 2 excel workbooks no?

Comment: When you keep opening/closing the same WB (`destFullpath`) for more than 50 times, expect trouble. Try to open it once then close it at the end.

Comment: Either something broke when you pasted or I don't see how this could ever work. You have `'Loop through each Excel file in folder`, `Set y = Workbooks.Open(destFullpath)`, `For i = 1 To y.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("M1")`, `Do Events` (which is unnecessary, but being a courteous Win citizen), `Set y = Workbooks.Open(destFullpath)`. You open a workbook, start a loop through all the worksheets, then attempt to open it again. I'm going to assume that was a copy-pasta error and you need to repost your code.

Comment: @A.S.H it breaks when i is equal to the emplacement of those 2, they are at the end of the serie. To be clear I have tried with 11 samples including those 2, the code breaks and so on the destination excel (the result column) I have 9 only!

Comment: Further to what @A.S.H said, there is no loop through the files in the folder! You open `Set y = Workbooks.Open(destFullpath)` where `destFullpath` is a fixed value.

Comment: @FreeMan the destination WB is the same, but the formula gets computed from those different files.

Comment: @A.S.H how can I do that? to open it and close it at the end? destFullpath is  the same but  I have 50 different myfile! that's why i have made a loop For! (I don't understand! )

Comment: By the way, you're not opening `myFile` so you have to provide it's path along with its name in the formula. I wonder how this worked for another workbooks but basically it should be: `.Formula = "='" & myPath & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!L2"`

Comment: No, your `destFullpath` is the same, both in the code and in the problem description: *"from multiple workbooks and paste it into a destination workbook "*. What is changing within the loop is the **source** file `myFile`.

Comment: @A.S.H but  `myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)` so if I write `.Formula = "='" & myPath & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!L2"` it will be like writing my path twice! right?

Comment: @A.S.H you are right! haha! sorry! i edited it but you didn't see!

Comment: remove the second occurrence of `Set y = Workbooks.Open(destFullpath)` and move the statement `y.Close saveChanges:=True` to after the end of the loop (the `Next` statement).

Comment: @A.S.H I tried it `.Formula = "='" & myPath & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!L2" `the code breaks at once!

Comment: The Problem is NOT in the code!! the problem is with the 2 excels workbooks! because everything work except when I have those 2 included in "myfile"!

Comment: If the problem isn't in the code, then tell us what error message you're getting when you attempt to open those 2 workbooks. Is it only and _always_ those two? Do you get the same error if if's only those 2 in the folder you're parsing? Can you create a copy of one of the "working" workbooks and make it the 51st one and see if it works OK with that many? You've written very difficult to read code, you've got people trying to help you and you're yelling at them when they try. That doesn't make people very willing to try to help further...

Comment: @UGP these two workbooks open in  Read-Only! i have unprotected them!

Comment: I would speculate that it's because you're using the poorly named `y` as the `workbook` variable to hold `destFullPath`, then you're opening `destFullPath` again (while it was already open), and assigning it again to `y`. If this is not the actual, breaking code, but a sample to show us the issues, it's not a very good sample.

Comment: @FreeMan I am not yelling at all, I am very greatfull for your help! I am saying the problem is not in the code because the code works always and everytime with any number!  the code breaks only and always with those 2!

Comment: @FreeMan I wish I can post screen shots to show you what i mean! maybe i am not clear as i am not english native :(

Comment: @FreeMan yes, the problem is with those 2 workbooks. I am 100% certain that the layout is identical! I can open them normally like the others! the code breaks means that when having those 2 with the others, the code runs when i is different from those 2 and when i is equal to one of them the process stops! for those 2 I am not getting any result => blank!

Comment: I apologize - you have given us the error message `1004` and the line it happens on. My bad - reading failure on my part. Again, my apologies! In that case, my guess would be an issue with the file name you're trying to open. Why don't you tell us what that file name is.

Comment: @FreeMan i have one workbook that i can't open when clicking on it (there is a problem with it) but this one doesn't stop or break the code. the process continues and it gives `#REF!` instead of blank as for the 2 famous workbooks

Comment: You're getting `#REF` because the value of `myFile` provided in the formula is invalid (blank) because you're getting an error when you're trying to execute `myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)`. Again, since this is the place where you're getting the error, and it only happens with these two files, _what are the names of the files that cause the problem_? My bet is that there is something in the file name like a `"`, or perhaps, since English isn't your native tongue, there's a unicode character in there that VBA is choking on.

Comment: It's hard to correlate the code with the question, since the code clearly doesn't do what you claim it does. Please [edit] your post to remove the fluff, clarify the problem statement and include an actual [mcve] that demonstrates and reproduces the problem. Continuing this comment thread is useless, if you want help you need to clarify your post.

Comment: When you are saying its in Read-Only and NOT protected View then they are opened somewhere else, you might want to look in the taskmanager for invisible excel applications and close them.

Answer (score 1):

You're not iterating 50 *workbooks*. You're iterating 50 *file names*.

```
.Formula = "='" & "[" & myFile & "]Para RF'!L2"
```

Error 1004 on this line means `myFile` somehow contains invalid characters, or (more likely) that there is no worksheet named `Para RF` in that workbook.

Try typing `='[that file name.xlsx]Para RF'!L2` directly in a cell (in any workbook). You'll see this:

[image: A formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references. Verify that your formula contains a valid path, workbook, range name, and cell reference.]

So, *Verify that your formula contains a valid path, workbook, range name, and cell reference.*

If there *is* such a `Para RF` sheet in the failing workbook, make sure there's no leading/trailing spaces.